# what is a live configuration file?

Tags: file, configuration, live

friends,
    recently i cam through this term "live configuration flle".what is this?why do we use this?
here is the text in which i found this "Software
installations like this one often ship with a sample configuration file to help guide
the process of setting up a custom configuration. Most users will simply edit this
file, changing only the settings that need to be changed for their environments,
saving the file not as a .sample file but as a .conf file. In this situation, the user
could have a live configuration file with the term zebra.conf.sample still in place.
".could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

From the text you provided, the term "live configuration file" appears to mean a configuration file that is being used by a running/deployed application.